# how to start a subprocess by signal boundary event without cancelling the user task

Tags: activiti

[image: workflow image]

As the posted photo, I want to create a subprocess by a signal boundary event. But when I test it, it ends the user task.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: which photo?, no attachments

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ul4a.png

Answer (score 1):

The boundary events has an option called `cancel activity`. if this is `true`, Activiti will cancel your task (on which you have applied the boundary event) and begins to execute path that you have created on the boundary event.

if you are using eclipse designer, click on your boundary event by keeping the activiti perspective. go to its **Properties**, then go to **Main config**, set `Cancel activity` to `false`.

This will allow your event path to be followed without getting your user task terminated.